# building Mozilla Spider Monkey on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, linux, mozilla

I'm trying to build spider monkey on ubuntu 10.04 (lucid). However, when I run autoconf2.13 on the js/src directory, it tells me there is no configure.in file. I can't just do the usual ./configure > make > sudo make install , either. What's up with it?

Comment: I know that you have asked for building Spider Monkey on Ubuntu, but in case someone just want to use it, Launchpad Developers PPA included a build of spidermonkey. sudo apt-add-repository ppa:launchpad/ppa then apt-get update and apt-get install spidermonkey-bin. Feel free to delete this comment if it is of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me works as follows in Ubuntu 10.04:

```
make BUILD_OPT=1 -f Makefile.ref
```

The option apparently is only for optimizing the code. Then I copy by hand the files where they should be to be used by my programs. I only really need the bin so it was easy.

Here you have the official documentation [the new one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey_Build_Documentation) that explain where to copy the headers and executables and [the old one](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/src/README.html) that I used for the compilation.

It was useful too [this link](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/src/README.html) and [this one](http://ebixio.com/blog/2010/07/31/how-to-install-libjs-spidermonkey/).

Answer (score 7):

Same thing happened here.  I think that they definitely could benefit from an build instructions update.

Here is what I had to do...

Download the latest source via mercurial - run the following and then go get some coffee (you make need to install Mercurial if not already install - repo version works fine):

```
hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/js
```

Then I had to cd in: `cd js/src`

Then you can pick up where the Mozilla instructions lead you:

```
autoconf2.13
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The command given in the previous answer results in 404 Not Found. I used:

```
hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central
```

which probably does the whole tree. And 1 cup of coffee will not be enough. Perhaps 3 pots, it takes agggggeeeesssss.

Comment: there is a link at http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ for a link to the bzip http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/archive/tip.tar.bz2 which speeds things up